# List of commands with --porcelain option available

Tags: git

Is there a public official (or maybe not) list of `git` commands, for which `--porcelain` option is available? Or should I manually review each of them in [the porcelain commands list](http://schacon.github.io/git/git.html#_high_level_commands_porcelain)?

I've managed to google the following three:

```
git status --porcelain
git push --porcelain
git blame --porcelain
```

But is there any more? And if not, can I find somewhere the information on whether any additional would appear and when?

**UPD:**
So here is the full list of collected currently available commands with `--porcelain` option (based on the answers below):

```
git annotate --porcelain
git blame --porcelain
git commit --porcelain
git push --porcelain
git status --porcelain
git worktree list --porcelain
```

Will try to keep it up-to-date with the new information available. Please if you find any new, leave a response in comments or as an answer.

Comment: What are you trying to do? what do you need it for?

Comment: @CodeWizard Nothing yet, just curious whether there is a full list. I know that in case of parsing it's recommended to use plumbing commands, but the commands with `--porcelain` option also implicitly guarantee the stability.

Comment: It will only effect the output to stdout not more than that

Comment: @CodeWizard I know that too :) I'm not yet doing anything, but I suppose it's easier to use the shorter `--porcelain` option, than compose a probably long plumbing command which would do effectively the same.

Comment: You can always use aliases instead. that's what im doing

Comment: There is only one more command with the `--porcelain` which is git worktree

Comment: In the manual there is a "Main porcelain commands" section if it can help.
It is not a list of commands accepting the --porcelain option though.

Comment: @J.P.Quenord-Zermingore that's a different thing.

Comment: Run `git --html-path` to find where the docs are. Then run `grep '\-\-porcelain' *.html` in that folder, which I think can give you the answer.

Comment: @ElpieKay almost. That will include `git ls-files` which does not have a `--porcelain` option but does have a discussion about `git status --porcelain` in its man page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can combine:

- [git/git/search?l=bash&q=porcelain](https://github.com/git/git/search?l=bash&q=--porcelain&utf8=%E2%9C%93)
- [git/git/search?l=c&q=porcelain](https://github.com/git/git/search?l=c&q=--porcelain&utf8=%E2%9C%93)

That will confirm you also have:

```
git commit --porcelain
git worktree list --porcelain
```

For more on the meaning of porcelain, see my answer "[What does the term “porcelain” mean in Git?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6978402/6309)"

> **The meaning of `--porcelain` here is "produce output suitable for consumption by porcelain scripts"**.

Note that [`git blame`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-blame) options can be passed around to other commands. That is why [`git annotate`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-annotate) *also* has a `--porcelain` option.

Also, grepping for `porcelain` in [Documentation](https://github.com/git/git/blob/c2c5f6b1e479f2c38e0e01345350620944e3527f/Documentation/)  would return [`git ls-files`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/c2c5f6b1e479f2c38e0e01345350620944e3527f/Documentation/git-ls-files.txt#L110-L116), which has *not* such an option, but refers instead to `git-status --porcelain` and `git-diff-files --name-status` as more user-friendly alternatives.

Answer (score 0):

As far as i know there is no documentation covering it.

Lets explain what it does for all of those who doesn't know so they can learn something new:

> **`--porcelain`**
>
> Produce machine-readable output.
>   The output status line for each ref will be *tab-separated* and sent to `stdout` instead of `stderr`.
>
> The full symbolic names of the refs will be given.

#### More commands:

- `worktrees --porcelain`
  [What is worktree? and when should i use it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39173008/git-where-do-files-go-when-you-change-branches/39174530#39174530)

You can also use `git status -z` which is equivalent to `git status --porcelain`

Comment: Actually, the `-z` option rather includes `--porcelain`, than is equivalent. From the docs: "Terminate entries with NUL, instead of LF. This implies the --porcelain output format if no other format is given."

Comment: I agree its exactly what it does